# Lower or upper case?

Tags: capitalization

Should I use capital or lowercase for a specific character mentioned in a spoken sentence?
Is it therefore 'the professor' or 'The Professor' if I am referring to a known
character in the story.
Many thanks,
TJ

Comment: Is "professor" just a general description, like "The doctor will see you now?"   If so, lowercase.  Or, is it a **title**, like "They call him The Professor because he's very knowledgable"?  if it's the latter then it's capitalized.

Comment: If you added a sample block of text it would help.